# H brige with LM324N

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a quartz movement run off an arduino and I can't seem to get the alternating +/- voltage right.

If I am not mistaken, this should be doable with a LM324N chip, but I don't understand how it works. The OUT pin is hot when I connect the Input- to ground and Input+ does not do anything. (OUT goes out when both are connected to ground.)

Can anyone help?

Comment: neither do we know how anything is wired on your side, nor can we do anything but guess what you mean by "make a quartz movement run off an arduino"

Comment: A quartz movement has a coil that rotates the first gear every second, but with alternating current. So +---(coil)---- - to - ---(coil)--- + powering it is easy, but i need to alternate the current direction.

Comment: So you don't want to move/excite a quartz crystal but you want to drive a mechanical clock (having nothing to do with a quartz)?

Comment: No, we can't.  You haven't explained what you really want to do, and what description there is makes little sense.  It's also clear that with your level of knowledge about opamps, you wouldn't be able to understand a proper answer.  This isn't a *gimme da codz* kind of site.  We are here to help those that want to understand something about electronics, not to serve up circuits.

Comment: you mean something like this http://www.cibomahto.com/2008/03/controlling-a-clock-with-an-arduino/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 3):

Quartz clock movements typically employ a Lavet-style single phase stepper motor that operates from a single cell voltage (~1.5V). Coil resistance is a few hundred ohms.

You should have three states in the output including de-energized. An LM324 can handle enough current.

So suppose you split a 5V supply with one op-amp of the LM324 to give you 2.5V you can then drive the other side of the coil with 0V/1V/4V to give the proper drive voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYLjJX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The P input should be low for de-energized
The /N input should be high for de-energized

> P = 0, /N = 1 for de-energized
>
> P = 1, /N = 1 for +
>
> P = 0, /N = 0 for -
>
> P = 1, /N = 0 (this is not a useful input)

Ideally the bias would be lower, more like 2.0V than 2.5 because the LM324 can't drive as close to the positive rail, but this should work as shown.

Note that some Arduinos don't have an accurate crystal timebase (they use ceramic resonators) so they won't be suitable for keeping time, at least not in a straightforward manner.